# Tensorflow Object Detection API gives Tfrecord files of 0 bytes size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to train a custom object detection model using TFOD, following [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) documentation. When I run the generate_tfrecord.py file, it gives generates tfrecord files of 0 bytes, I don't know what wrong it used to work previously.

```
 # Create train data:
 !python generate_tfrecord.py -x /content/drive/MyDrive/training_demo/images/train -l /content/drive/MyDrive/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt -o /content/drive/MyDrive/training_demo/annotations/train.record

# Create test data:
!python generate_tfrecord.py -x /content/drive/MyDrive/training_demo/images/test -l /content/drive/MyDrive/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt -o /content/drive/MyDrive/training_demo/annotations/test.record
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for a long time. I'm working in a university cloud and my repository doesn't have a Tensorflow folder, and I've built a folder structure starting from the workspace folder. According to the tutorial, the generate_tfrecord.py script should be in the TensorFlow/scripts/preprocessing folder. I had it elsewhere. As a result, everything worked when I created the preprocessing folder in the folder above the workspace folder and moved the script there. It is not at all clear why this caused problems, since the script is called from a folder, and I specified absolute paths.